# Slick slider no event thrown if only 1 item

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, slider, slick.js

I have implemented a slick slider that handles dynamic data.  The issue I have is when there remains just one slide.  In that case no event is thrown.  In case this 'slide' is a video item, i need to recycle it from the start when the end of the video has reached.
I even implemented a trigger in the slick code, but it seems this trigger is not thrown either (if just one slide).

```
    Slick.prototype.changeSlide = function(event, dontAnimate) {

    var _ = this,
        $target = $(event.currentTarget),
        indexOffset, slideOffset, unevenOffset;


    _.$slider.trigger('recycle', [_, event]);
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this event is thrown now (in a previous version i added other arguments which could maybe cause the event not being thrown).

I hope this event will be added in a new version.